# Function not recognizing page id?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to setup an if/then statement so that if the page_id is not one of these three pages or their ancestors, then use the default logo. I'm using the is_tree() function in my functions file and resetting the post data before I call it.

But it only works if I comment out the last "else" (/home) statement. If I leave that last else statement, it doesn't recognize the `page_id` and doesn't show the right logo (home shows on 'conway').

When I do a var dump on the queried object, the correct ID does show.

Here is my `is_tree` function:

```
function ac_my_tree() {
   function is_tree($pid)
{
  global $post;

  $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->$pid);
  $root = count($ancestors) - 1;
  $parent = $ancestors[$root];

  if(is_page() && (is_page($pid) || $post->post_parent == $pid || in_array($pid, $ancestors)))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
};
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ac_my_tree');
```

And here is the if/then in my template file:

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php 
/*
    Which logo do we use?
*/
if (is_tree('33') ) { // if is conway
    $logoClass = 'logo-conway '; 
    $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/conway';

} elseif (is_tree(35) ) { // if is cullowhee
    $logoClass = 'logo-cullowhee ';
    $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/cullowhee';

} if (is_tree(31) ) { // if is Johnson City
    $logoClass = 'logo-johnson-city ';
    $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/johnson-city';

} else { // if is something else
    $logoClass = 'logo-home';
    $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/home';
}

?>
```

EDIT: Sorry, I have an "if" in the middle of my if/then. It has been a long day.

Comment: It looks like you don't check your PHP scripting errors. Did you know about [this Codex page on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? If not you should check it out. This [paranoia config setup file](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) by @kaiser might also help you. PS: You have some problems in your code, for example this one: `$post->$pid` and `function ac_my_tree() { function is_tree($pid) {`.

Comment: Thanks @birgire, I've turned on debugging, and yes, i do get a Notice: Undefined offset: -1 , but I've turned that on for some other sites I've used this on, and it works even if I get that error. Not sure what exactly is wrong with what you're saying above either, those come from examples in the wordpress codex on conditional tags.

Comment: Good, the first step is always to turn the debug ON for the test site. Try for example to move the `is_tree()` function out of the `ac_my_tree()` function. I'm not sure what you're doing with the `wp_head` hook. Then notice that `is_tree( '33' )` gives you `$post->'33'` in one code line. But I think this is more of a PHP question, than WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

missing "else" in the 3rd elseif.

```
 <?php 
/*
Which logo do we use?
*/
if (is_tree('33') ) { // if is conway
  $logoClass = 'logo-conway '; 
  $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/conway';

} elseif (is_tree(35) ) { // if is cullowhee
  $logoClass = 'logo-cullowhee ';
  $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/cullowhee';

} elseif (is_tree(31) ) { // if is Johnson City
  $logoClass = 'logo-johnson-city ';
  $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/johnson-city';

} else { // if is something else
  $logoClass = 'logo-home';
  $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/home';
}

?>
```